# Minimum Value of a complex expression

Tags: complex-numbers

Find Minimum value of  $\dfrac {\mathrm{Im}~ z^5} {(\mathrm{Im}~ z)^5}$ for $z = x+iy$.

Here I started with $z = r \exp(i \theta)$
solve the expression finally i got the answer in terms of $\tan$ which i find little difficult to get along with

Answer (score 2):

If we set $z=x+iy$

Using Binomial Theorem,

$z^5=(x+iy)^5=x^5+\binom51x^4(iy)+\binom52x^3(iy)^2+\binom53x^3(iy)^3+\binom53x(iy)^4+(iy)^5$

$=\cdots+i\{\binom51x^4y-\binom53x^2y^3+y^4\}$

So, img$(z^5)=\binom51x^4y-\binom53x^2y^3+y^4=5x^4y-10x^2y^3+y^4$

$$\implies \frac{\text{img}(z^5)}{(\text{img}(z))^5}=5\left(\frac xy\right)^4-10\left(\frac xy\right)^2+1=5\left(\left(\frac xy\right)^2-1\right)^2+1-5\ge-4$$

The equability occurs when $\left(\frac xy\right)^2-1=0\implies \frac xy=\pm1\iff x=\pm y$

---

If we start using polar coordinate,

as $\displaystyle \frac xy=\frac{r\cos\theta}{r\sin\theta}=\cot\theta$

we shall reach at $\displaystyle 5\cot^4\theta-10\cot^2\theta+1=5(\cot^2\theta-1)^2+1-5\ge-4$

Comment: Yep this is correct . is it possible to solve this using derivative test for maxima minima. Like if i put x/y = t and then minimizing the function 5t^4-10t^2+1..

Comment: @MilanAmrutJoshi, have you tried http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test ?

Comment: Nice solution lab bhattacharjee......